# Given Hamilton's Principal Function, $S(\alpha, \beta, t)$, prove that $p$ and $q$ are canonical variables

Tags: homework-and-exercises, coordinate-systems, hamiltonian-formalism, phase-space, poisson-brackets

I've been self teaching using Hamill's Student's Guide to Lagrangians and Hamiltonians. (I know it's a terrible text to work from, but I'm almost done!) I'm stuck on problem 6.5 that basically asks, given Hamilton's Principal function, $S(\alpha, \beta, t)$, prove that $p$ and $q$ are canonical variables.

Here is the full question:

> $6.5\;\; $We have expressed Hamilton's principal function as $S(q_{i},\alpha_{i},t)$. Show that $q_{i},p_{i}$, are canonical variables, recalling that 
>   $$p_{i}=\frac{\partial S}{\partial q_{i}},$$
>   $$q_{i}=q_{i}(\alpha,\beta,t),$$
>   where 
>   $$\beta_{i}=Q_{i}=\frac{\partial S}{\partial \alpha_{i}},$$
>   and
>   $$\alpha_{i}=P_{i}.$$

I've tried showing that the poisson bracket $\{q,p\}$ equals one. I've also tried showing that Hamilton's equations hold, but I've had no luck. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I don't think that picture is enough to work from.

Answer (score 0):

You were given $p_{i}=\frac{\partial S}{\partial q_{i}}$ but do you have enough information to invert it?

Since, $$S(q_{i},\alpha_{i},t)$$

and

$$q_{i}=q_{i}(\alpha_{i},\beta_{i},t)$$

then

$$ p_{i}=\frac{\partial S(q_{i}(\alpha_{i},\beta_{i},t),\alpha_{i},t)}{\partial q_{i}}$$

The answer is yes - there's enough information to invert it since $\alpha_{i}$ and $\beta_{i}$ are initial constants.

Hence, $p_{i}$ can be written as

$$p_{i}=p_{i}(\alpha_{i},\beta_{i},t)$$

Are $q_{i},p_{i}$ canonical?